# tomcat: How to trace out connections leak?

Tags: java, apache, tomcat

We are running web application hosted over Tomcat and it's creating lot of connection leaks.

How to find/trace out  **Leak Connections** in Tomcat?

Comment: Try a thread dump (kill -3 the JVM) and analyze it

Comment: What do you mean by connection leak ! Are you talking about DB Connections ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use profilers for this. 
For example using Yourkit you can find out the increase connection objects and then trace the allocation point of these connections.

Comment: @Deepak..yes, i mean DB Connections only..

Comment: jprofiler, i know.. but i havn't tried configuring it yet...  does tomcat provide something for this?  I read somewhere org.apache.commons.dbcp.AbandonedTrace, seems like tomcat has something..any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the Tomcat connection pool, you can set **logAbandoned** property to true.

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html